# While loop stops for a reason I did not anticipate in python

Tags: python, while-loop

Am very new to python, I'm just using it to solve some of Euler's problems. I'm stuck on problem 4 as my code keeps stopping for no apparent reason. Its attempting to find the largest palindrome product of two three digit numbers.

```
x = 100
y = 100

while x != 1000:
    test = x * y
    if str(test)[::-1] == str(test):
        ans = test
    elif y<1000:
        y += 1
    else:
        x += 1
        y = 100
        print(x)
print(ans)
```

If I run it all I see is that 1 is added to x only one time, though it should happen 899 times. I know the rest of the code is working as it finds 10201 which is 101 * 101 but nothing after that.

I've tried changing the loop to while a variable stop is false and setting it true when x == 999 but it still stops after x == 101. Why does my loop stop?

Comment: is the loop stopping or never exiting? it looks like x is only incremented ovcassionally.  maybe you want to take the line `x += 1` out of the else block.

Comment: sorry guys just realized that when an answer is found it will never do anything else gonna fix that ill get back to you

Comment: Since you loop through both x and y, from 100 to 1000 apparently, why not use a nested for loop, outer for x and inner for y? I think that amounts to what you intent with this while loop, but is far easier to comprehend.

Comment: Please think carefully about the logic. For example: is it possible that `str(test)[::-1] == str(test)` can happen? (For example, when `x` is equal to `101`)? If that happens, do you expect `x` to be incremented? Why or why not? (Hint: where is the code that says `x += 1`? Is it inside the `else` block, or outside? Does that make sense? Should it happen every time through the loop, or only conditionally?)

Comment: as an aside, this is better served as nested `for` loops rather than a single `while`.    Generally anytime you're incrementing a variable manually, you're better off with a for, or in this case 2.

Answer (score 0):

this line `elif y<1000:` should be an `if` not an elif: you rporgram is stuck in an infite loop not increasing x neither y once it finds the first palindrome.

Your while loop is not "stopping": you'd see your program finish, and get back to console, or whatever: as it is, it will keep running forever. Even for getting this one correct result, you likely had a different program than this: this won't print even the answer for "101".

After you fix that, move your print to inside the while loop, unless you want to see just the last result (although, IIRC the largest number is usually what Project Euler problems require - it would be ok then)

Comment: Please read [answer] and don't attempt answers for questions that are demonstrably caused by a typo or an elementary logic error. We don't find the bug here; we require questions to be potentially of use to others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you find the first palindrome that matches the condition 'str(test)[::-1] == str(test)', which is x=101 & y= 101, you stay stuck in this statement and will never increase x or y again.

Replacing the **elif** with an **if** will cycle through all the possibilities x,y -> (100..999)

As requested in ProjctEuler task 4, you need to **Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.** So store the largest answer found somewhere and compare it with the actual answer to keep the greatest

```
x = 100
y = 100

LargestPalindrome =0

while x != 1000:
    test = x * y
    if str(test)[::-1] == str(test):
        ans = test
        if ans > LargestPalindrome:
            LargestPalindrome = ans
    if y<1000:
        y += 1
    else:
        x += 1
        y = 100
print(LargestPalindrome)
```

There is a lot of code optimization to make it faster but the code works. Try improving this code if you want to solve a more difficult problem on ProjectEuler, good luck! :)